# Can't understand error message when working with Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I can read from a row and column in the database, but when I want to write to the same place I get an error message and I don't understand what could be wrong?

I get this error messgage:

> Dynamic sql generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against
>   a SelectCommand     that does not return any key column information

My code:

```
    public void LoadData()
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        dataset = new DataSet();

        sql = "SELECT * From Guests";

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            adapter.Fill(dataset, "Guests");
            connection.Close();

            string test = Convert.ToString(dataset.Tables["Guests"].Rows[0][1]);
            MessageBox.Show(test, "This is only a test!",
                   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

            dataset.Tables["Guests"].Rows[0][1] = "Hello";

            connection.Open();
            new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.Update(dataset.Tables["Guests"]);
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/200154/Error-Dynamic-sql-generation-for-the-update-comman

Comment: check if your table has a primary key specified or not.

Answer (score 2):

In you SelectCommand you must return primary key, because SqlCommandBuilder need to generate the update, and you must set primary key on your table

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.90).aspx

"The SelectCommand must also return at least one primary key or unique column. If none are present, an InvalidOperation exception is generated, and the commands are not generated."

Comment: Hmm, how can I see if I have a primary key in my DB and can I add one if not to an already existing DB Visual Studio?

Comment: I read some of the text in the link and I could also use a unique column, but I det get it if I should just add one column, the one I'm updating with a new value, or all columns?

Comment: Open your table, and verify if you have primary key on table

Comment: you can add all columns in the first time, i think that you have primary key

Comment: Yes I think so to! I haven't been working with databases for some time, and I'm trying to remember my old knowledge. I have an ID column that must be the primary key. But I don't get how I should return this. I don't see any such thing in the code on the microsoft site. Can you show where and how this should be done?

Comment: access table properties et verify key section, search primary key

Answer (score 0):

Your select query needs to return the primary key of the table.  If your table doesn't have a primary key, you need to set one. Be ensure that your table contain primary key....